# AcrUserDialogs Toast Position

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using AcrUserDialogs on a Xamarin project. My problem is that I need to display a toast in the top of the screen. By default they are displayed in the bottom. I see that AcrUserDialogs toasts have a `ToastPosition` setting but I can't seem to find how to initialize that:

```
UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Awesome message to user.");
```

I even downloaded the AcrUserDialogs repository code but I'm just stuck on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `DefaultPosititon` property in the static class `ToastConfig`.

```
Acr.UserDialogs.ToastConfig.DefaultPosition = ToastPosition.Top;

Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.InfoToast("I should be shown at the top");
```

Comment: Your code compiles but app crashes at runtime without a warning. Why don't they have this work:
            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(new ToastConfig("Cool message")
            {
                Position = ToastPosition.Top
            });

Comment: I updates Acr.UserDialogs package and it worked. Thanks a lot.